# PowerPoint reader (.ppt)

Tags: 7

I searched for a PowerPoint player (ppt from Microsoft Office) but I couldn't find what i needed.
Is there a module that can display PowerPoint files on Drupal sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Embedded Google Docs Viewer](http://drupal.org/project/gdoc_field) module:

> The Embedded Google Docs Viewer module adds a new formatter to the File field using the Field API. This formatter displays PDFs, Microsft Word documents, Powerpoint presentations, or Excel spreadsheets directly within a Drupal node.

There's a tutorial that details how to use it on the module page.

Comment: I installed this module and when upload pptx file this message appear ---'Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists.
You can also try to download the original document by clicking here.
'---  
the files i want  to upload it's locally creating not from internet. how can i solve this problem

Comment: @abd  Your comment is a separate issue from your question.  Try asking it separately so site users are aware of it.

Comment: I upload ppt, but show No preview available.